# Calling Apex Function from VF Page Convention

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm a little confused on what the convention/syntax is to call a controller function from a VF component.

For ex.

```
<apex:commandButton value="=>" action="{!giveChild}" reRender="panel1"/>
```

Controller function :

```
public void giveChild() {
    String curr = childObjToMig;
    if(curr!=null) {
        migrateList.add(new SelectOption(''+curr.toUpperCase(),''+curr)); //Error
        disableChild(curr);
    }
    return;
}
```

Is this the proper convention of calling the function?...and I'm confused if I'm calling the function in the right convention because I do remember reading that in VF `{!function}` gets translated to `getFunction()` in the controller when its looking for it. I'm a bit confused if I'm thinking of this right and would like a clarification

Edit : Error fixed, need more understanding convention

Comment: that is the correct way. You have issue at some other place. Please put more specific details.

Comment: why is that for function calls, for ex. `{!function}` translates to `getFunction()` in Apex and is that consistent? Because in this case its going to the function and not looking for a `get` function

Comment: It will not it will be giveChild only in your case.

Answer (score 4):

Functions called from *value* or *assignTo* attributes (or are otherwise directly inlined), use the get/set prefix. Functions called from *action* attributes are called verbatim. For example, given this code:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!myTextField}" />
<apex:commandButton value="{!buttonLabel}" action="{!doAction}" />
```

The corresponding Apex Code looks like:

```
String myText;
public String getMyTextField() {
    return myText;
}
public void setMyTextField(String value) {
    myText = value;
}
public String getButtonLabel() {
    return 'Hello World';
}
public void doAction() {
    System.debug('I debugged this text in the log.');
}
```

In other words, if the function is placed in a context where a value should be returned, it uses get. If the function is placed in a context where a value should be applied, it uses set. Finally, if neither of the two are true, then it will be called directly without get or set.